# Vb.NET : Draw row number in list view

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview, row, gridlines

Greeting everyone, I have a question regarding drawing row numbers in ListView like I did in DataGridView. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

In my DataGridView, I draw the row number using this code :

```
Private Sub SalesDGV_RowPostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles SalesDGV.RowPostPaint
    'draw the row number
    Using b As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(SalesDGV.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.RowIndex + 1, _
                               SalesDGV.DefaultCellStyle.Font, _
                               b, _
                               e.RowBounds.Location.X + 20, _
                               e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4)
    End Using
End Sub
```

And the result in my DataGridView: http://puu.sh/3h4CF.png

I want my ListView row numbers have the exact same style as my DataGridView, but it seem that ListView doesn't support such style in default and I need a custom control (?)

I know some people will suggest me to use back DataGridView instead, but the reason I use ListView instead is that because DataGridView will give me void area if I don't populate data, while ListView allow me to have GridLines without populating any data.

So I have two question here :

- How do I draw row headers with numbers in ListView like I did in DataGridView?
- Can I have gridlines display in DataGridView even through I don't populate any data? If possible, how can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I have gridlines display in DataGridView even through I don't
>   populate any data? If possible, how can I achieve it?

If you populate a datatable with spaces and use that as a datasource your gridview will have gridlines but appear to have no data.

Something like this:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Column to hold row numbers
    dt.Columns.Add(" ")
    'Number of columns
    For I = 1 To 5
        dt.Columns.Add(I.ToString)
    Next
    'Number of rows
    For I = 1 To 10
        'Extra column holds the row number
        dt.Rows.Add({I.ToString," ", " ", " ", " ", " "})
    Next
    SalesDGV.DataSource = dt
```

> how do I insert it so that the gridlines is still there and that the
>   data is insert in row accordingly?

put the data into the datatable. Just check for null data and make it a space instead. If you're adding the data from a database, one way is to loop through the columns and rows of the datatable looking for empty data and changing it to a space. If the data is from a file you probably already have a loop that you can use to modify the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have through of this before, but what if I want to insert a data into my DataGridView, how do I insert it so that the gridlines is still there and that the data is insert in row accordingly?

Comment: Thanks Sir, I got how it work already! Your solution really help me a lots and save me tons of time, thanks! :)